# Is it possible to mix OnIdiom and OnPlatform in XAML (Xamarin.Forms)?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-devices, mobile-development

For UWP I need a different size for the width of a column in a `Grid`. Additionally, the value should be different on tablet and on smartphone.

The following code crashes the app

```
<ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition.Width>
        <OnIdiom.Phone>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="GridLength" iOS="*" Android="*" WinPhone="100" />
        </OnIdiom.Phone>
        <OnIdiom.Tablet>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="GridLength" iOS="*" Android="*" WinPhone="200" />
        </OnIdiom.Tablet>
    </ColumnDefinition.Width>
</ColumnDefinition>
```

with

> Type OnIdiom.Phone not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

The code is in a `ViewCell`. So I can't use an additional `ResourceDictionary` and also `OnSizeAllocated()` is not available in the code behind file.

Is it possible to use `OnIdiom` and `OnPlatform` together?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`OnIdiom`, just like `OnPlatform` is an object you have to declare. In your case, you're setting `OnIdiom.Phone` property to an object that doesn't have those.

Your Xaml should look more like:

```xml
<ColumnDefinition>
  <ColumnDefinition.Width>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="GridLength">
      <OnIdiom.Phone>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="GridLength" iOS="*" Android="*" WinPhone="100" />
      </OnIdiom.Phone>
      <OnIdiom.Tablet>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="GridLength" iOS="*" Android="*" WinPhone="200" />
      </OnIdiom.Tablet>
    </OnIdiom>
  </ColumnDefinition.Width>
</ColumnDefinition>
```

Comment: I tried to run the app on the local machine. Here the 200 width is not respected. Shouldn't it fall into the `Tablet` category?

Comment: `Device.OS` is `Windows` and `Device.Idiom` is `Desktop`. Are there any definitions for that in the XAML available? `WinPhone` worked fine before.

Comment: support for `Desktop` in OnIdiom landed a few days ago https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/420. The fix will be present in the upcoming 2.3.4-pre1

Answer (score 18):

Much nicer syntax as of Xamarin.Forms v3.2 (via new built-in XAML extensions):

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{OnIdiom 
        Phone= {OnPlatform iOS=*, Android=*, UWP=100 },
        Tablet= {OnPlatform iOS=*, Android=*, UWP=200 }}">
    </ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: What if i want to add the padding like iOS= 10,5,10,5 , Android="15,10,15,10". How to add values that require a comma like padding?

Comment: Just use single quotes, e.g. iOS='10,25'

Answer (score 4):

`Xamarin.Forms` Xaml Example:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
    <OnPlatform.Android>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="GridLength" Tablet="100" Phone="50" />
                    </ColumnDefinition.Width>
                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="GridLength" Tablet="100" Phone="50" />
                    </ColumnDefinition.Width>
                </ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </OnPlatform.Android>
    <OnPlatform.iOS>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="GridLength" Tablet="100" Phone="50" />
                    </ColumnDefinition.Width>
                </ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="GridLength" Tablet="100" Phone="50" />
                    </ColumnDefinition.Width>
                </ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
    </OnPlatform.iOS>
</OnPlatform>
```

Comment: OK, I multiply the complete `Grid` definition. But I have a few named `Label` in it and one can't have multiple labels with the same name. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution to mix OnIdiom and OnPlatform in xaml. For Example, there are variations in stack layout padding then we can do this as follows -

```
   <StackLayout.Padding>
                        <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                        <OnIdiom.Phone>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0,40,0,0" Android="15,0" WinPhone="15,0" />
                        </OnIdiom.Phone>
                        <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="15,0" Android="15,0" WinPhone="15,0" />
                        </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                      </OnIdiom>

</StackLayout.Padding>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option which works in code is to use

```
if(Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows && Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
    this.innerGrid.ColumnDefinitions.First().Width = new GridLength(100);
```

to overwrite the existing Xaml definition. `innerGrid` is the name of the `Grid` used in the Xaml.