# How can I achieve four spaced buttons on an iPhone that fill the screen and on bigger than an iPhone that fill half the screen?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to have four buttons like this:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="buttonGrid" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="20, 0">
    <Button x:Name="zeroButton" Text="0" HeightRequest="60" BackgroundColor="#2D7BF7" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
    <Button x:Name="oneButton" Text="1" HeightRequest="60" BackgroundColor="#2D7BF7" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
    <Button x:Name="twoButton" Text="2" HeightRequest="60" BackgroundColor="#2D7BF7" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
    <Button x:Name="fiveButton" Text="5" HeightRequest="60" BackgroundColor="#2D7BF7" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
</Grid>
```

On an iPhone or a small mobile I would like to have these fill 90% of the screen width.  But on a bigger screen I would like the buttons to only fill 50% of the screen width.

Can anyone suggest to me how I can do this?

Comment: use OnIdiom to specify a different layout for phone and tablet

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know anything about that. Is that what many people use?

Comment: yes, XF provides OnIdiom for specifically this case: where you want to have different behavior on Phone and Tablet.

Comment: Jason - Can you provide an example.  Btw I will probably open up a bounty for this question in the next 24 hours :-)

Comment: have you attempted to search?  There are numerous examples out there, like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111252/is-it-possible-to-mix-onidiom-and-onplatform-in-xaml-xamarin-forms.  You can also create separate XAML layouts for each idiom and just select which one to call programatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Explanation

If you need to create layouts that reference the `ContentPage.Width` or `ContentPage.Height` properties, the best way to do it is by using a `RelativeLayout`.

If you try referencing the `ContentPage.Width` or `ContentPage.Height` properties directly, you will find that Xamarin.Forms returns `-1`. This is because `-1` is the default value that Xamarin.Forms uses when it hasn't instantiated the control yet.

`RelativeLayout` uses `Func`s to dynamically reference the page's `Height` and `Width` properties and will return the true value of the `Height` and `Width` properties once the `ContentPage` has been instantiated.

## Code

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HorizontalButtonSampleApp
{
    public class ButtonPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ButtonPage()
        {
            const int relativeLayoutHorizontalSpacing = 5;
            const int numberOfButtons = 4;

            double screenUsePercentage;
            if (Device.Idiom.Equals(TargetIdiom.Phone))
                screenUsePercentage = 0.9;
            else
                screenUsePercentage = 0.5;

            var zeroButton = new StyledButton { Text = "0" };
            var oneButton = new StyledButton { Text = "1" };
            var twoButton = new StyledButton { Text = "2" };
            var fiveButton = new StyledButton { Text = "5" };

            var relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();
            relativeLayout.Children.Add(zeroButton,
                                        Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => parent.Width * (1 - screenUsePercentage) / 2),
                                        Constraint.Constant(0),
                                        Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => (parent.Width * screenUsePercentage - relativeLayoutHorizontalSpacing * (numberOfButtons - 1)) / numberOfButtons));
            relativeLayout.Children.Add(oneButton,
                                        Constraint.RelativeToView(zeroButton, (parent, view) => view.X + view.Width + relativeLayoutHorizontalSpacing),
                                        Constraint.Constant(0),
                                        Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => (parent.Width * screenUsePercentage - relativeLayoutHorizontalSpacing * (numberOfButtons - 1)) / numberOfButtons));
            relativeLayout.Children.Add(twoButton,
                                        Constraint.RelativeToView(oneButton, (parent, view) => view.X + view.Width + relativeLayoutHorizontalSpacing),
                                        Constraint.Constant(0),
                                        Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => (parent.Width * screenUsePercentage - relativeLayoutHorizontalSpacing * (numberOfButtons - 1)) / numberOfButtons));
            relativeLayout.Children.Add(fiveButton,
                                        Constraint.RelativeToView(twoButton, (parent, view) => view.X + view.Width + relativeLayoutHorizontalSpacing),
                                        Constraint.Constant(0),
                                        Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => (parent.Width * screenUsePercentage - relativeLayoutHorizontalSpacing * (numberOfButtons - 1)) / numberOfButtons));

            Content = relativeLayout;

            Padding = new Thickness(0, 20);

            Title = $"Button Page on a {Device.Idiom}";
        }
    }

    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ButtonPage());
        }
    }

    public class StyledButton : Button
    {
        public StyledButton()
        {
            TextColor = Color.Black;
            HeightRequest = 60;
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("2D7BF7");
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
        }
    }
}
```

## Tablet Screen Shot

[image]

## Phone Screen Shot

[image]

Comment: Hi Brandon, I am sorry but what I need is them to be spaced horizontally.  Sorry for the confusion. If you would like to amend your answer for that then I can accept.

Comment: No problem, @Alan! I edited the code above so that the buttons are spaced horizontally! I also created a new class called `StyledButton` that inherits from `Button`. Because each button has similar properties, we are able to set the similar properties once in `StyledButton` and reuse its code!

Comment: great answer, Given that Xamarin doesn't recommend Relative layout (though I personally unfortunately love it) I would also recommend to check AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: Hi Brandon,  My page is already set up with a StackLayout with Grids inside of that.  Do you feel that I could achieve the same thing with a relative layout for the other parts of my page and then add your button code to the bottom of that?

Comment: Yea, definitely! You want to avoid nesting StackLayouts anyway. The Grid won’t work in this case simply because we need to reference the Parent’s width.

Comment: @Alan If you specify what you already have and to what place you want to insert those buttons it will be easier to give you more detailed answer. If you want to insert them to grid then the size of the whole grid should change.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, I will specify what I have now in another question and then open that up with another bounty in about 48 hours.  I'm using XAML so would be interested to see if you could come up with any suggestions as to how the XAML could be improved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640548/how-can-i-change-a-stacklayout-grid-screen-to-use-relativelayout.  The question is quite complicated so you might want to wait until I open a bounty for it in a couple of days.  Thanks