# New OnPlatform/OnIdiom XAML Extension - Usage for Margin Thickness

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms 3.2.0, Xamarin Forms introduced new New **OnPlatform/OnIdiom XAML Extension**

As per the [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-3-2-0-released-going-big-with-little-things/) we can re-write the below code,

```
<Button Text="Extensions" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White">
<Button.HeightRequest>
     <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Default="40">
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="60"/>
        <On Platform="Android" Value="80"/>
    </OnPlatform>
</Button.HeightRequest>
```

with the new extension.

```
<Button Text="Extensions" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" 
    HeightRequest="{OnPlatform iOS=60, Android=80, Default=40}"/>
```

Here my doubt is how I can reuse the same **OnIdiom XAML Extension** for **Margin / Thickness.**

Comment: Use the extended property format, rather than the inline property format.

See this other article which will walk you through it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40111252/is-it-possible-to-mix-onidiom-and-onplatform-in-xaml-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this: `<Button Margin="{OnPlatform Android='10,5,10,0', iOS='10,20,10,0'}" />`

It's up to you which syntax you like more!

Comment: How to use OnIdiom for Phone and Tablet with OnPlatform like this?

Comment: @Divyesh_08 did you found out how? I am currently handling the same question...

Comment: @Dior No, not yet